# What happens on a wifi-only iPad that wants to use core location?

Tags: ipad, gps, core-location

A business customer reports that the app I made for him crashes on his iPad. It crashes just after starting up.

I tested on several iPads without issues. The only thing I can think of is that he has a wifi-only iPad without GPS. And my app uses core-locations.

I implemented the

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager 
   didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {}
```

So I thought it would be fine.

But could the use of core location be the reason that the iPad crashes? I know I can solve this with *UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities*

Comment: What does the crash log say? Ask the client to bring you their iPad so you can connect it and view the crash logs in Xcode.

Comment: I did ask for it and gave him the instructions. But I dont think he will. Thanks for tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this should not be the reason that the iPad crashes. For example, this works fine on the wifi-only iPad (just tested):

```
if (self.locMgr == nil)
{
    self.locMgr = [[[CLLocationManager alloc] init] autorelease];
    self.locMgr.delegate = self;
}

if (self.locMgr != nil)
{       
    if ([self.locMgr respondsToSelector:@selector(startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges)])
    {
        [self.locMgr startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
    }

    [self.locMgr startUpdatingLocation];
}
```

}

It doesn't crash, it even starts the location monitoring based on wifi signals.